# Service wont Start

Tags: android-activity, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm trying to get a service started that will run in the background as long as the Navigation Activity is running.  The trouble is that the service doesn't appear to be starting.  The application doesn't crash, it tries to start the service as far as I can tell, but nothing seems to happen.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Also I'm trying to use a local broadcaster to send strings of data from the service to the calling activity, have I implemented it correctly?  Finally, I cant seem to get the Navigation activity to execute the run(), what is the best way to do this so run() is called repeatly until the activity is closed? This is my first attempt at making an android application, so explain in newbie terms :)  Thanks

FYI MainActivity Starts Navigation Activity, which starts Service AugiActivity

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void call_ioio(View v)
{   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AugiActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void navigation(View v)
{   
    System.out.println("Got to Mainactivity start Navigation");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Navigation.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Navigation Activity:

```
public class Navigation extends MapActivity implements Runnable, 
SurfaceHolder.Callback{

String LED = null;
String MAG = null;
String BAR = null;
String GYRO = null;
String EULER = null;    
String GGA = null;

private BroadcastReceiver MessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        LED = intent.getStringExtra("LED");
        MAG = intent.getStringExtra("MAG");
        BAR = intent.getStringExtra("BAR");
        GYRO = intent.getStringExtra("GYRO");
        EULER = intent.getStringExtra("EULER");
        GGA = intent.getStringExtra("GGA"); 
        run();
    }
};

boolean previewing = false;
boolean map_view = true;
boolean cam_view = false;
boolean sen_view = false;

LinearLayout SS;
SurfaceView CC;
MapView MM;

TextView light_voltage_TV;
TextView bar_data_TV;
TextView mag_TV;
TextView gyro_TV;
TextView gyro_rate_TV;
TextView acel_TV;
TextView acel_euler_TV;
TextView gga_TV;
TextView gsa_TV;
TextView gsv_TV;
TextView rmc_TV;
TextView vtg_TV;

// CAMERA VARIABLES
    Camera cam;
    SurfaceView cam_TV;
    SurfaceHolder holder;       

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);   

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

    cam_TV = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CAMERA_View);
    holder = cam_TV.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback((Callback) this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(MessageReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter("IOIOData"));

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            // Lots of linking view variables to xml views here

    System.out.println("Got to Navigation OnCreate");
    startService(new Intent(this, AugiActivity.class));     
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void sensorLayer(View v)
{
    // set view visable/invisible
}

public void mapLayer(View v)
{
    //set view visable/invisible
}

public void cameraLayer(View v)
{
    //set view visable/invisible
}   

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Got to Navigation RUN");

    //update text views with string data
}
}
```

AugiActivity:

```
public class AugiActivity extends Service { 

public Activity activity_name;

class IOIO extends IOIOActivity {   


// Various unrelated global variables

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    activity_name = this.getParent();
    System.out.println("Got to AugiActivity OnCreate");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.        
    return true;
}

class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {

    public Activity activity_name;

    Looper(Activity x)
    {
        this.activity_name = x;
    }       

    // Communication variables

    /**
    * Called every time a connection with IOIO has been established.
    * Typically used to open pins.
    *   
    * @throws ConnectionLostException
    *             When IOIO connection is lost.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
    * 
    * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity.IOIOThread#setup()
    */
        @Override
        protected void setup() throws ConnectionLostException, 
InterruptedException 
        {
            // OPEN LIGHT SENSOR PINS


            // ESTABLISH I2C CONNECTION


            // ESTABLISH UART CONNECTION                

            bar_calibration();      
            mag_setup();
            imu_setup();    
            try {
                gps_setup();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // BAROMETER CALIBRATION METHOD
        private void bar_calibration()
        {
            // do setup
        }

        // MAGNETOETER SETUP METHOD
        private void mag_setup()
        {
            // do setup
        }

        // IMU SETUP METHOD
        private void imu_setup()
        {
            // do setup
        }

        private void gps_setup() throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {               
            // do setup     
        }

    /**
    * Called repetitively while the IOIO is connected.
    * 
    * @throws ConnectionLostException
    *             When IOIO connection is lost.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
    * 
    * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity.IOIOThread#loop()
    */


    @Override
        public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException, 
InterruptedException 
        {           
            get_light();

            get_temp();

            get_pressure();

            get_north();

            get_imu();

            System.out.println("Got to AugiActivity LOOP");
            try {
                get_gps();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            led_.write(true);   

            sendMessage();
        }

        private void get_light()
        {
            // get data
        }

        private void get_temp()
        {
            // get data
        }

        private void get_pressure()
        {
            // get data
        }

        private void get_north()
        {
            // get data
        }

        private void get_imu()
        {
            // get data
        }

        private void get_gps() throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {   
            // get data 
            }

        private void sendMessage()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("IOIOData");     

            intent.putExtra("LED", get_LED());

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity_name).sendBroadcast(intent);

            intent.putExtra("MAG", get_MAG());

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity_name).sendBroadcast(intent);

            intent.putExtra("BAR", get_BAR());

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity_name).sendBroadcast(intent);

            intent.putExtra("GYRO", get_GYRO());

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity_name).sendBroadcast(intent);

            intent.putExtra("EULER", get_EULER());

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity_name).sendBroadcast(intent);

            intent.putExtra("GGA", gps_GGA);

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity_name).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
    /**
    * A method to create our IOIO thread.
    * 
    * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity#createIOIOThread()
    */
    @Override
    protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
        return new Looper(activity_name);
    }       

    public String get_LED()
    {
        // code here            
    }

    public String get_MAG()
    {
        // code here
    }

    public String get_BAR()
    {
        // code here            
    }

    public String get_GYRO()
    {
        // code here            
    }

    public String get_EULER()
    {
        // code here            
    }

    public String get_GPS()
    {
        // code here            
    }

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.onBind(intent);
}   
}
```

Comment: Im still stuck here.  Any advice on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but here you have an activity within a service.
You call `startService()` with an `Intent` that starts `AugiActivity` which is a service (hard to follow you with this kind of names).

The problem I see is that you didn't even implement the `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, and `onDestroy()` methods of your service. In this methods you could manage the lifecycle of the nested object you have here.

Anyway, I believe having an Activity within a Service is not really clean. What is your purpose exactly? Why do you have a nested activity? You don't seem to have any layout for it (maybe I missed it, but there is a lot of code! :D), so why not just stay in the service itself, instead of performing everything in a nested class?

If you want to have a user interface that communicate with a background service, then you can use an activity that binds to a service (but create 2 different classes: one for the service, one for the activity with the interface). Take a look at [bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) in Android developer guide.